# Module 'pylab' has no attribute 'scatter'

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics, linear-regression

I am working on a linear regression model for stock ticker data, but I can't get Pylab working properly. I have successfully plotted the data, but I want to get a line of best fit for the data I have.  (Not for any particular purpose, just a random set of data to use linear regression on.)

```
import pylab
import urllib.request
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def chartStocks(*tickers):

    # Run loop for each ticker passed in as an argument
    for ticker in tickers:

        # Convert URL into text for parsing
        url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=" + str(ticker) + "+Historical+Prices"
        sourceCode = requests.get(url)
        plainText = sourceCode.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plainText, "html.parser")

        # Find all links on the page
        for link in soup.findAll('a'):
            href = link.get('href')
            link = []
            for c in href[:48]:
                link.append(c)
            link = ''.join(link)

            # Find the URL for the stock ticker CSV file and convert the data to text
            if link == "http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=":
                csv_url = href
                res = urllib.request.urlopen(csv_url)
                csv = res.read()
                csv_str = str(csv)

                # Parse the CSV to create a list of data points
                point = []
                points = []
                curDay = 0
                day = []
                commas = 0               
                lines = csv_str.split("\\n")
                lineOne = True
                for line in lines:
                    commas = 0
                    if lineOne == True:
                        lineOne = False
                    else:
                        for c in line:
                            if c == ",":
                                commas += 1
                            if commas == 4:
                                point.append(c)
                            elif commas == 5:
                                for x in point:
                                    if x == ",":
                                        point.remove(x)
                                point = ''.join(point)
                                point = float(point)
                                points.append(point)
                                day.append(curDay)
                                curDay += 1
                                point = []
                                commas = 0
                points = list(reversed(points))

                # Plot the data
                pylab.scatter(day,points)
                pylab.xlabel('x')
                pylab.ylabel('y')
                pylab.title('title')

                k, b = pylab.polyfit(day,points,1)
                yVals = k * day + b
                pylab.plot(day,yVals,c='r',linewidth=2)
                pylab.title('title')

                pylab.show()


chartStocks('AAPL')
```

For some reason I get an attribute error, and I'm not sure why.  Am I improperly passing in data to `pylab.scatter()`?  I'm not totally sure if passing in a list for x and y values is the correct approach.  I haven't been able to find anyone else who has run into this issue, and `.scatter` is definitely part of Pylab, so I'm not sure whats going on.

Comment: Try `plt.scatter()`!

Comment: Hmm, that seems to eliminate the scatter error, but it causes a new error on the line `k, b = plt.polyfit(day,points,1)`.  `module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'polyfit'`.  If I leave it as `pylab.polyfit()` I get the original error I was having `Pylab has no attribute 'polyfit'`

Comment: This code could really benefit from a refactor, if you can get it working and want some advice on improving the code then this would be a really good candidate to post over on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Also correct me if I'm wrong but isn't `polyfit` found in `numpy` or `scipy`?

Comment: You're actually totally right.  I was using an old tutorial that was using only pylab for this.  I guess a lot has changed since that tutorial was made, but I got it working now.  (Just had to use numpy instead.)  Also, thanks for the pointer to codereview.stackexchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use pylab it imports some other packages. So when you do `import pylab` you get  numpy with the prefix `np` so you would need `np.polyfit`. As this question shows I think it's clearer to the readers of the code if you just import numpy directly to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I think that there is a version clash. Try:

```
plt.pyplot.scatter(day,points)
```